# WCF The Client and Service may be mismatch error

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, wshttpbinding, bizagi

I am working on Web Service WCF application. This service take your name as parameter and return text. So idea is to test this service with Bizagi. The Bizagi successfully implement helloService with basicHttpsBinding for end-point but when I change binding protocol to wsHttpBinding it give me following error;

I have HTTPS configured on IIS 7. The above service is deployed on IIS 7.

[image]

System.ServiceModel End-point Defination

```
<!--*************** SYSTEM SERVICES MODEL AND CONFIGURATION ****************-->
<system.serviceModel>
 <!--*** Services ***-->
 <services>
  <service name="App.Services.Managers.HelloWorldManager" behaviorConfiguration="EBSMiddlewareBehaviorDefault">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="App.Services.Contracts.IHelloWorldService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<!--*** Bindings ***-->
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<!--*** Behaviour ***-->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EBSMiddlewareBehaviorDefault">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<!--*** Service Hosting Environment***-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add service="App.Services.Managers.HelloWorldManager" relativeAddress="EBSMiddlewareServices.svc"/>
  </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <!--*********** Service Perfromance Counter **************-->
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="All"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<!--END SYSTEM SERVICES MODEL-->
```

Comment: Did you update the client config to use `wsHttpBinding` as well?

Comment: I am trying to consume these service in Bizagi and I am not sure how to activate in that!